# escaping | in batch for loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, escaping

I have a loop

```
for /f "usebackq" %%u in(...) do SET heel=!heel! ^^^| ooo
```

if im appending variable that way im getting error

`ooo is not recognized as an internal or external command`

How can I escape | char?
If im not appending that variable im not getting that error

Comment: You are properly escaping the `|` in the statement you have shown (assuming delayed expansion is enabled). The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Slight correction, you only need `^|`. The extra `^^` is not needed, but neither does it do any harm. `set heel=!heel! ^| ooo` and `set heel=!heel! ^^^| ooo` yield the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%u in(...) do SET "heel=!heel! | ooo"
```

though if you type

```
echo %heel%
```

you'll get the same error again (but you can use `echo "%heel%"` or if you are still under delayed expansion `echo !heel!`).

Comment: @Dainius - are you sure you are getting the error on this point , but not somewhere later in the script? Check where `heel` variable is used.